# Modifying headers of outgoing NServiceBus subscription messages to pass information to IAuthorizeSubscriptions

Tags: nservicebus

I am using NServiceBus 4.4.2 and I have created a class which implements `IAuthorizeSubscriptions` in order to accept/reject subscriptions. I need some additional information in the publisher  about the subscriber, so I tried creating a class which implements `IMutateOutgoingTransportMessages` and registering it in the normal way using `ConfigureComponent<MyMutator>(DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerCall)`. All this class does is add a header to the outgoing message.

Unfortunately the headers aren't set on the subscribe control message when sent from the subscriber. I've checked that if the subscriber does a Bus.Send() that my custom headers *are* appended to the transport message's Headers collection so I don't think it's a problem with my mutator, unless I need to register it differently.

Is there a way to get headers appended to the subscription messages, or am I going about this the wrong way and should pass the information by some other means?

**Edit:**

**Mutator Code:**

```
public class MyMutator : IMutateOutgoingTransportMessages
{
    public void MutateOutgoing(object[] messages, TransportMessage transportMessage)
    {
        transportMessage.Headers.Add("CustomHeader", "Test");
    }
}
```

**IAuthorizeSubscriptions Code:**

I can set a breakpoint inside the `AuthorizeSubscribe` method and it gets hit, but `headers` doesn't contain my custom header.

```
public class SubscriptionAuthoriser : IAuthorizeSubscriptions
{
    public bool AuthorizeSubscribe(string messageType, string clientEndpoint, IDictionary<string, string> headers)
    {
        // headers doesn't contain the "CustomHeader" header

        return true;
    }

    public bool AuthorizeUnsubscribe(string messageType, string clientEndpoint, IDictionary<string, string> headers)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Per this conversation (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/particularsoftware/XVLQkCouKCk), as of v4.3, IMutateOutgoingTransportMessages implementations are no longer used on outgoing subscription messages.

Comment: Good find. Thanks for posting the link. Although it does make me sad that it is no longer possible. If you post it separately, I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of NServiceBus version 4.3, InvokeOutgoingTransportMessagesMutators is no longer called on outgoing subscription messages, so it appears this is no longer possible with message headers.  I asked a similar question a while back @  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/particularsoftware/XVLQkCouKCk.  While I was waiting for a response on the aforementioned thread, I implemented a temporary workaround, which was a manual subscription method (constructed using mostly NServiceBus Unicast bus source).  This is probably not recommended, but I figured I'd post it anyways it case it helps someone.

```
public void Subscribe(Type eventType, Address targetAddress)
{
    var transportMessage = new TransportMessage
        {
            ReplyToAddress = Address.PublicReturnAddress,
            Recoverable = true
        };
        transportMessage.Headers.Add("NServiceBus.ControlMessage", true.ToString());
        transportMessage.Headers["SubscriptionMessageType"] = eventType.AssemblyQualifiedName;
        transportMessage.MessageIntent = MessageIntentEnum.Subscribe;

        var fdqn = OutgoingTransportMessageMutator.GetLocalhostFqdn();
        transportMessage.ReplyToAddress = new Address(transportMessage.ReplyToAddress.Queue, fdqn);

        string fullPath = MsmqUtilities.GetFullPath(targetAddress);
        try
        {
            using (var messageQueue = new MessageQueue(fullPath, false, false, QueueAccessMode.Send))
            {
                using (var message1 = MsmqUtilities.Convert(transportMessage))
                {
                    message1.UseDeadLetterQueue = false;
                    message1.UseJournalQueue = false;
                    message1.ResponseQueue = new MessageQueue(MsmqUtilities.GetReturnAddress(transportMessage.ReplyToAddress.ToString(), targetAddress.ToString()));
                    messageQueue.Send(message1, MessageQueueTransactionType.Single);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (MessageQueueException ex)
        {
            if (ex.MessageQueueErrorCode == MessageQueueErrorCode.QueueNotFound)
            {
                string message1 = targetAddress == (Address)null ? "Failed to send message. Target address is null." : string.Format("Failed to send message to address: [{0}]", targetAddress);
                throw new QueueNotFoundException(targetAddress, message1, ex);
            }
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.Error(ex);
            throw;
         }
     }
```